# UTL_FILE: Could not create a new file

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm using this statement in ly code to create/open à file: create it if does not exist yet/open it if already exists.

```
   w_file_handle := utl_file.fopen ('SAUV_DIR',
                                'sauv_tab_tbrcs_params.txt' ,
                                'W') ;
```

The file doesn't exist yet but it couldn't be created.

I got this error:

```
SQL> @MyScript.sql
declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at line 14
```

Any ideas to create the file if doesn't exist yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer this code to create a file in your directory.

I created a tt.sql file with the below code. I checked that i have a working directory 'BDUMP`.

Directory Check:

```
SQL> SELECT DIRECTORY_NAME , DIRECTORY_PATH FROM DBA_DIRECTORIES WHERE DIRECTORY_NAME = 'BDUMP';

DIRECTORY_NAME                 DIRECTORY_PATH
------------------------------ ---------------
BDUMP                          /home/fil_test/
```

Change directory permission. By default it has only Read and execute permission for others.

```
terminal$ chmod 777 fil_test
```

Block:

```
DECLARE
   fHandle   UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
   fHandle := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('BDUMP', 'test_file', 'w');

   UTL_FILE.PUT (fHandle, 'This is the first line');
   UTL_FILE.PUT (fHandle, 'This is the second line');
   UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE (fHandle, 'This is the third line');

   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE (fHandle);
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (
         'Exception: SQLCODE=' || SQLCODE || '  SQLERRM=' || SQLERRM);
      RAISE;
END;
/
```

Execution:

```
SQL> @tt.sql

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

And i See the file created:

```
terminal$ ls -lrt test_file*
-rw-r-----   1 oracle   dba           68 Oct 24 14:49 test_file
```

Comment: I executed by 
    `begin
    Read_Writ_file();
    end;`
I have the same error:
29283. 00000 -  "invalid file operation"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to read from a file or directory that does
           not exist, or file or directory access was denied by the
           operating system.
*Action:   Verify file and directory access privileges on the file system,
           and if reading, verify that the file exists.

Comment: ...But it executed successfuly when I create the file manually in the directory. 
I want that it's be created by the statement.

Comment: @O.Sam it means the directory doesnot exist in your case. Check if the directory exists. Read updated post. Also give permission `777` to your directory

Comment: Thanks @XING, the directory exists. I didn't give the permission. The script is executed successfuly (:y)