# Utl_file package error

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I tried to execute the below code and it went to successful. But in directory I didn't see my file.

```
declare 
    fp utl_file.file_type;
    cursor c1 is select * from apr where rownum<=10;

begin
    fp:=utl_file.fopen('FLAT_FILE_DIR','test2.txt','W');

    for i in c1
    loop
        utl_file.put_line(fp,i.TERM_PERIOD||'  '||i.FLAT_RATE_APR||'  '||i.APR);
    end loop;

    utl_file.fclose(fp);
 end;
```

Comment: Do you have any data from that query?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UTL\_FILE: Could not create a new file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910797/utl-file-could-not-create-a-new-file)

Comment: Works for me. What is the location of `FLAT_FILE_DIR`?  Sometimes people expect Oracle to write to their local desktops, when it can only see the database server and filesystems shared to it. Could this be the issue?